# MeteorJs Find all users with an array of user IDs

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongoose

How can I get every user that has an ID in an array of user IDs.
My problem is I have a collection of groups, each group has an array of userIDs called users, these users belong to the group, I need to know how to get the user objects from that array of UserID's whats the best way to do that?

client

```
export default createContainer((props) => {
  let user = Meteor.users.findOne(Meteor.userId())
  let groupsSub = Meteor.subscribe('groups')

  if (user) {
    let code = user.profile.selectedGroup
    let group = Groups.findOne({code})
    return {
      ready: groupsSub.ready(),
      group,
      users: Meteor.users.find({_id: {$in: group.users}}).fetch()
    }
  }

  return {}
}, HomePage)
```

sever

```
 Meteor.publish('groups', function () {
 return Groups.find({
   users: {
     $elemMatch: { $eq: this.userId }
   }
 })
})
```

and this is where I'm trying to get the users

```
   render () {
    if (this.props.ready) {
    let group = this.props.group
    let users = this.props.users
    console.log(users)

    return (
      <div className='c-fit-group'>
        <div className='c-fit-group__header'>
          <h1>{group.name}</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
     )
   }

   return <div>Loading...</div>
  }
}
```

also I'm using React for the front end

when I console.log group.users I get this
[image]

and when I console.log users I get this 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you simply have an array of the user ids (i'm having trouble telling if that's the issues you're trying to solve), you can use the $in operator. e.g.

```
let userIds = ['abc', 'def', 'hgi'];
let userCursor = Meteor.users.find({_id: {$in: userIds}});
```

to just get the results instead of a cursor:

```
let userResults = Meteor.users.find({_id: {$in: userIds}}).fetch();
```

**update:**

from your comment about not getting all the users on the client, is there somewhere where you're actually publishing the users? i think that's the part you're missing.

you can return multiple cursors from a publish, e.g.

```
Meteor.publish('groups', function () {
    let groupsCursor = Groups.find({
        users: {
            $elemMatch: { $eq: this.userId }
        }
    });

    // find these from... ???
    let userIds = [];

    let usersCursor = Meteor.users.find({_id: {$in: userIds}});

    return [groupsCursor, usersCursor];
});
```

Comment: when I do this I get back an object localCollection.Cursor I have no Idea what that is :P would I expect that to give me an array of user objects?

Comment: @GavynCaldwell, no, find() returns a cursor over which you can iterate, if you want. if you just want the results, you can also call fetch. i'll update the answer with an example.

Comment: okay I just tried using .fetch() which only returns one of the users. There are at least 2 users on the array

Comment: I am super new to mongo and meteor so thank you for the help!!

Comment: @GavynCaldwell, i'm unsure why. i just double-checked my code in a browser and it worked as expected -- exactly what i have above except i used real user ids. can you update your question with your code? also, if you're running this code on the client, are you sure you've published all the users you expect to find?

Comment: something weird just happened. I didnt do anything to my publications or subscriptions and now my app is returning nothing!

Comment: could you edit your question and format the code there? also indicate what is client code and what is server code please.

Comment: I did that for ya!

Comment: for what you have marked as "client", is that inside a createContainer() for the React component? if so, i've only done a find/fetch in there, not a findOne(). it might work the same way, but if not maybe there's a timing issue there. i.e. maybe the findOne() isn't reactive, and that might account for your inconsistent results.

Comment: also yes that is in a create container.

Comment: I added more code and changed a little bit so you could see better how I am doing everything

Comment: I should also mention that autopublish is off, I just did a publication to get all users on the server but its still only giving me the logged in user

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation if you are looking for all users in entire collection.

The initial stage finds all matching `userIds` in each document and followed by `$group` to get the distinct users across the collection.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        userIds: {
            $setIntersection: ["$userIds", [1, 2, 3]]
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwinds: "$userIds"
}, {
    $group: {
        $id: null,
        userIds: {
            $addToSet: "$userIds"
        }
    }
}])
```